# Quotation mark style changed and is no longer recognized in my HTML editor

Tags: html, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

This is probably a stupid keyboard shortcut that I inadvertently activated but I've Googled and searched stack and can't figure out what I did.

I was editing some HTML in my editor and Alt+Tabbing back and forth between my browser.  I seem to have inadvertently hit some key combination in my haste that switched my "quotes" to something stylized - like a curly quote.  Sausage fingers.

The problem is that my HTML editor is no longer recognizing them as quotes.

Any idea what I did?

Comment: And what text editor are you using ?

Comment: It's doing it in both Dreamweaver and Expression Web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably hit "alt-shift" that switch langage/keyboard layout in Windows. Press "alt-shift" to switch back